Sum Over Min Die
Question: You have been tasked to find the expected value of a die game in which you are rolling
2 dice at a time. Your first roll of the dice will all be summed up and will be your starting score. Your next, and final, roll of the
2 dice will be your divisor, in which you are going to pick the optimal die out of the two to divide your total by, which will be your final score.
Calculate the expected value of playing this game optimally.
Why is the following reasoning incorrect:

Let $X$ be the sum of the first rolls of the dice and $Y$ be the minimum of the second rolls of the dice. Then we want to calculate $E(\frac{X}{Y}) = \frac{E(X)}{E(Y)}$ since X and Y are independent events.
$E(X) = 2*3.5 = 7$
$E(Y) = \frac{11}{36} * 1 + \frac{9}{36} * 2 + \frac{7}{36} * 3 + \frac{5}{36} * 4 + \frac{3}{36} * 5 + \frac{1}{36} * 6 = \frac{91}{36}$
So we get $E(\frac{X}{Y}) = \frac{E(X)}{E(Y)} = \frac{7}{\frac{91}{36}} = \frac{36}{13}$


Note that $E[\frac 1Y]\neq \frac {1}{E[Y]}$.

The same computation you did for $E[Y]$ enables you to compute $E\left[\frac 1Y\right]$.  As we have $E\left[\frac XY\right]=E[X]\times E\left[\frac 1Y\right]$ your argument goes through as before.

The only mistake you are making is that $$\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] \ne \frac{\operatorname{E}[X]}{\operatorname{E}[Y]}.$$  While for independent events, the relationship $$\operatorname{E}[XY] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]$$ is true, the same is not true for $\operatorname{E}[X/Y]$.
To calculate the desired expectation, you must compute
$$\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right] = \sum_{a=1}^6 \sum_{b=1}^6 \frac{A+B}{\min(A,B)} \Pr[A = a]\Pr[B = b],$$ where $A$ and $B$ are the outcomes of the two die rolls.  Since $\Pr[A = a] = \frac{1}{6}$ and $\Pr[B = b] = \frac{1}{6}$, this computation should not be too difficult.
